# Conditional aggregation with MAX and without group by

Tags: hive

So I have a data quality check query where I have a field called RunNumber that identifies if\when data is appended. It can have a value of 1 or 2, but is not limited to just 2. I can't use Group By, as you'll see in the query - there are hundreds and thousands of CASE statements. I can't seem to get the query to run in Hive. I get a "...Expression not in GROUP BY key '0'..."

```
SELECT MaxRun = MAX(RunNumber)
,FirstName = SUM(CASE WHEN FirstName IS NULL OR FirstName = 'NULL' OR FirstName = ' ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FirstName
,LastName = SUM(CASE WHEN LastName IS NULL OR LastName = 'NULL' OR LastName = ' ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LastName
,State = SUM(CASE WHEN State IS NULL OR State = 'NULL' OR State = ' ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS State

FROM Table.Customers
WHERE DateOfRecord = '2023-05-01'
```

The output that I'd like to get is:

| MaxRun | FirstName | LastName | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 750 | 1000 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you change your query like this `  MAX(RunNumber) as MaxRun` and so on, it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Tried that, still get the "expression not in GROUP BY key '0'. What's interesting is that even after I added GROUP BY just for a test, I got the correct MaxRun, but all "False" results for all of the rows returned

Comment: canyou pls add correct SQL ? its hard to say antything without looking at your SQL. Also pls attach sample input data.